# Is it true that $ U \oplus W_1 = U \oplus W_2 \implies W_1 = W_2 $?

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum, vector-space-isomorphism

Is it true that if $ U \oplus W_1 = U \oplus W_2 $, then $ W_1 = W_2 $? I think that if $ U \oplus W_1 = U \oplus W_2 $, then $u+w_1=u+w_2$, so $W_1=W_2$. But did I make any mistakes?

Comment: No $u+w_1=v+w_2$ for some $u,v\in U$.

Comment: no, you can't, @David. $U\oplus W=U$ only when $W=\{0\}$. $\oplus$ means something different from $+$.

Comment: Does the $\oplus$ mean orthogonal sum?

Comment: But what if U, W1, W2 are subspaces of V?

Comment: ⊕ means direct sum or the sum of two disjoint vector spaces

Comment: It's still not true, @권예준

Comment: Then take $U=\operatorname{sp}\{e_1\}, W_1 = \operatorname{sp}\{e_2\}, W_2=\operatorname{sp}\{e_1+e_2\}$ for a counterexample.

Comment: It might be worth noting that, although the answer to the literal question is "no", with the obvious counter-examples given, it does follow that $W_1$ is _isomorphic_ to $W_2$ (because they are (isomorphic to) the quotients of the big thing by $U$).

Answer (score 8):

Just consider $V=\mathbb R^2$, $$U=\{(x,0)\mid x\in \mathbb R\}\\W_1=\{(0,y)\mid y\in \mathbb R\}\\W_2=\{(y,y)\mid y\in \mathbb R\}$$